# Checking if variables match table row in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have tried a million different solutions and cannot seem to figure this one out. I am (right now) just trying to pull all instances from the DB that the email and key match and display them but I keep getting 
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Key = abaa937f092451741dfe172e51f68f69 AND Email= test@test.com'"
Not sure where I am going wrong but it is likely a simple solution.

```
//check if the key is in the database
$check_key = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM confirm WHERE Key = '$key' AND Email= '$email'")
or die(mysqli_error($con)); 



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_key)) {
  echo $row['Email'] . " " . $row['Key'];
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`key` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. Either use backticks to escape it or use another name.

```
SELECT * FROM confirm 
WHERE `Key` = '$key' ...
```